# Authenticate to Salesforce in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, oauth, salesforce

I am trying to authenticate to Salesforce in Chrome extension, but I am getting 400 error. If I try this code in Express.js server, it works.

**background.js**

```
console.log("Extension loaded");

let user_signed_in = false;
const clientId =
  "xyz";
const callbackUrl = "https://dfghlbaebomdoihlfmegbpcmfkfgfno.chromiumapp.org";

const getSalesforceLoginLink = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${callbackUrl}`
  );

  if (res.status === 200) {
    // append login link
    return res.url;
  } else {
    console.error("Not able to fetch login link");
  }
};

const authenticateSalesforce = (salesforceLink) => {
  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
    {
      url: salesforceLink,
      interactive: true,
    },
    function (redirect_url) {
      const codeParam = searchParams.get('code');
      let authCode = codeParam;
      const loginUrl = `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=${
    process.env.SALESFORCE_CALLBACK_URL
  }&client_id=${process.env.SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${
    process.env.SALESFORCE_CLIENT_SECRET
  }&code=${encodeURIComponent(authCode)}`;
  const response = await fetch(loginUrl)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response?.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      return data;
    });
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        sendResponse({ message: "fail" });
      } else {
        console.log({ redirect_url });
      }
    }
  );
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.message === "login") {
    if (user_signed_in) {
      console.log("User is already signed in.");
    } else {
      const salesforceLink = await getSalesforceLoginLink();
      authenticateSalesforce(salesforceLink);
    }

    return true;
  } else if (request.message === "logout") {
    user_signed_in = false;
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "./popup.html" }, () => {
      sendResponse({ message: "success" });
    });

    return true;
  }
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "SF POC",
  "description": "A quick way to browse top posts from DEV Community.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "action": {
    "default_title": "SF POC"
  },
  "key": "xyz",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["identity", "activeTab", "tabs", "windows"],
  "host_permissions": ["https://login.salesforce.com/*"]
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pointing to my answer on [Salesforce stackexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/400982/3901)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is due to the use of the fetch API to get the Salesforce login link. Chrome extensions follow the same-origin policy, so you cannot make cross-origin requests using the fetch API. In this case, you should directly use the URL constructed for Salesforce login as the URL parameter for `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`.

Additionally, there seems to be an issue with the authenticateSalesforce function, as you are using the await keyword inside a non-async function. You should wrap the callback function with an `async` function to avoid errors.

Here is the modified `background.js` file:

```js
console.log("Extension loaded");

let user_signed_in = false;
const clientId = "xyz";
const callbackUrl = "https://dfghlbaebomdoihlfmegbpcmfkfgfno.chromiumapp.org";

const getSalesforceLoginLink = () => {
  return `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${callbackUrl}`;
};

const authenticateSalesforce = (salesforceLink) => {
  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
    {
      url: salesforceLink,
      interactive: true,
    },
    async function (redirect_url) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        sendResponse({ message: "fail" });
      } else {
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(new URL(redirect_url).search);
        const authCode = searchParams.get("code");
        // Continue with your authentication flow using the authCode
        console.log({ redirect_url });
      }
    }
  );
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.message === "login") {
    if (user_signed_in) {
      console.log("User is already signed in.");
    } else {
      const salesforceLink = getSalesforceLoginLink();
      authenticateSalesforce(salesforceLink);
    }

    return true;
  } else if (request.message === "logout") {
    user_signed_in = false;
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "./popup.html" }, () => {
      sendResponse({ message: "success" });
    });

    return true;
  }
});
```